# Incidence Risk Ratio for combined risk factor outcome in Poisson regression

Tags: r, regression, survey, poisson-regression

I am analysing a large household survey. I specified the survey design based on the survey ids, stratum, weights, and data. So far have been able to get results using the original design. Presently, I have had to recode some risk factors of interest into 0 and 1. I will put the total count of the risk factors into a Poisson regression model to check the association with some explanatory variables
My survey designs

```r
mydesign <- svydesign(ids=~ids, strata=~Stratum, 
    weights=~Surveyweight, data=Country data)
```

I have nine risk factors and created a data frame for them to get the total risk factors for each person.

```r
Riskcombine <- data.frame(Risk1, Risk2, Risk3, Risk4, Risk5, Risk6, 
                          Risk7, Risk8, Risk9)
```

Then,

```r
countryrisk <- cbind(Riskcombine, total = rowSums( Riskcombine, 
                     na.rm= TRUE))
```

Therefore, each person’s risk: `countryrisk$total`
I tried putting the total into the Poisson regression model but kept getting an error message:

```r
Error in svyglm.survey.design(~Risk1 + Risk2 + Risk2 +  : 
  all variables must be in design= argument
 Error in svyglm.survey.design (countryrisk  ~ Age + resident +  
    education + wealth index + employment +  : 
  all variables must be in design= argument
Error in svyglm.survey.design (countryrisk$total ~ Age + resident + 
 education + wealth index + employment: 
  all variables must be in design= argument
```

Is there a way to update the design to accommodate the new variables (`Risk1`, `Risk2`, `Risk3`, `Risk4`, `Risk5`, `Risk6`, `Risk7`, `Risk8`, `Risk9`)? Also, which of the variable should be included in the model (`Riskcombine`, `countryrisk` or `countryrisk$total`)?

Comment: hi!  seems like a programming issue..  could you please modify your question so it's a minimal reproducible example?  maybe check out ?svyglm for some starting code and small objects that you can assemble to look similar to what you're seeing -- that might make it easier for others to help you  :-)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico. Thanks. summary(svyglm(sch.wide~ell+meals+mobility, design=dstrat, family=quasipoisson())).                    
  Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': all variables must be in design= argument

Comment: `summary(svyglm(as.numeric(sch.wide=='Yes')~ell+meals+mobility, design=dstrat, family=quasipoisson()))`   works fine for me?